# how to select multiple words in the same filed , they have the same file wav?

Tags: php, sql, symfony

i i want to select the info by the file link , for example in database in first line :

file link :  src/java/son3.wav | word : mailing

secund line in DB : file link : src/java/son3.wav  | word: smtp

3rd line in DB  : file link : src/java/son2.wav | word : server

I want to show like this in the html.twig ::

id : 1 | file link : src/java/son3.wav | word : mailing , smtp 
id : 2 | file link : src/java/son2.wav | word : server

so that select all the words in DB that have the same file link, I hope this explains what I'm after.

I'm using symfony 3.4 and this is how it showed in my interface :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQ63.jpg

this is pic of my table in DB :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEYaJ.jpg

```
this is the code of file twig :

  <table  class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                  <th>File Link</th>
                  <th>Words</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          {% for result in resultats %}
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="{{ path('result', { 'id': result.id }) }}">{{ result.id }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ result.indexeFichier.fichierUrl }}</td>
                  <td>{{ result.indexeMot.motValeur }}</td>




              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

and this is the code of file controller :

```
  public function IndexAction()
    {


      ////////////////////////////////////////////
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $resultats = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Indexe')->findAll();
      return $this->render('userfiles/result.html.twig', array(
          'resultats' => $resultats,
      ));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to do it only with DQL query, post processing can help:

public function IndexAction()
    {

```
  ////////////////////////////////////////////
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $tmp = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Indexe')->findAll();
  $tmp2 = [];
  foreach ($tmp as $v) {
      if (!isset($resultats[$v->getIndexeFichier()->getFichierUrl()])) {
          $resultats[$v->getIndexeFichier()->getFichierUrl()] = [];
      }
      $resultats[$v->getIndexeFichier()->getFichierUrl()][] = $v->indexeMot()->getMotValeur();

  }

  $resultats = [];
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($tmp2 as $k=>$v) {
      $resultats[] = ['id' => $i++, 'fichierUrl' => $k, 'motValeur' => join(', ', $v)];
  }

  return $this->render('userfiles/result.html.twig', array(
      'resultats' => $resultats,
  ));

}
```

and in template

```
  ....
  {% for result in resultats %}
        <tr>
          <td><a href="{{ path('result', { 'id': result.id }) }}">{{ result.id }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ result.fichierUrl }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.motValeur }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  ....
```

also if your db is mysql, you can try to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

Comment: that function show nothing in the table in page html.twig bro , it show table vide ,